# Postgresql issue on Manjaro 21.2.1

Tags: manjaro, postgresql, ruby, rails

It was working just fine a couple of months ago, but now it just returns the following, any ideas why libldap-2.4.so.2 could not be found all of the sudden?

OS: Manjaro 21.2.1

```
~ postgres --version                           
postgres: error while loading shared libraries: libldap-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
➜  ~
```

OR

```
~: rails server
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
/home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
Traceback (most recent call last):
        56: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
        55: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
        54: from /home/zil/DEV/RAILS/launch_calendar/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
        53: from /home/zil/DEV/RAILS/launch_calendar/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
        52: from /home/zil/DEV/RAILS/launch_calendar/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
        51: from /home/zil/DEV/RAILS/launch_calendar/bin/spring:10:in `require'
        50: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        49: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        48: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/spring-3.0.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        47: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        46: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        45: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        44: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        43: from /home/zil/DEV/RAILS/launch_calendar/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
        42: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        41: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        40: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        39: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        38: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        37: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        36: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        35: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        34: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        33: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        32: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        31: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
        30: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `tap'
        29: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `block in perform'
        28: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
        27: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
        26: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
        25: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        24: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        23: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        22: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        21: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        20: from /home/zil/DEV/RAILS/launch_calendar/config/application.rb:20:in `<main>'
        19: from /home/zil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
        18: from /home/zil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
        17: from /home/zil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
        16: from /home/zil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'
        15: from /home/zil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `each'
        14: from /home/zil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        13: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        12: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        11: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        10: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         9: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
         8: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:5:in `<main>'
         7: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
         6: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
         5: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
         4: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
         3: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         2: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
         1: from /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.9.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': libldap_r-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/zil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg_ext.so (LoadError)
```

Comment: Is the libdap package installed?

Comment: yes, it is installed